# Drag And Drop LibGDX

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, draggable, libgdx

I want to make a game where you can build stuff by dragging and dropping objects into place. I think LibGDX only supports DragNDrop on Actors, but I need physics on bricks in order to make them fall down if the construction is not stable.

So far, my approach to drag and drop is:

```
for(Brick b : map.getList()){

        final Image im = new Image(b.ar);

        stage.addActor(im);
        im.setPosition(b.posX, b.posY);
        im.setOrigin(b.posX, b.posY);

        im.addListener((new DragListener() {
            public void touchDragged (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer) {
                    im.setOrigin(x, y);
                    im.setPosition(x, y);
                    //System.out.println("touchdragged ---> X=" + x + "  , Y=" + y);


                }

            }));
    }
```

where the map.getLists contains all bricks to be painted. b.ar is the texture to be painted.

With this aproach [[this]](http://v5.tinypic.com/player.swf?file=330b9g5&s=5) is what happens. I don't know what may be causing it.

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    spritebatch.begin();
        map.getWorld().step(1/60f, 6, 2);
        renderer.render(map.getWorld(), camera.combined);

        if(Gdx.input.justTouched()){
            Vector3 touchPoint = new Vector3(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(),0);
            camera.unproject(touchPoint.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0));

            System.out.println(touchPoint);
        }


        stage.draw();
    spritebatch.end();
}
```

Of course i'd like to make the body fell (with the box 2d engine from libgdx) if you drop the object and it has nothing under it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're setting the origin in your listener callback to a screen coordinate.  That is not going to work.

The origin is used to define the "center" of your object, so when you reposition it, Libgdx knows which part of the actor to put where.  Generally the origin is either the bottom left corner of the object (I think this is the default) or its the center of the object.

I guess you may want to reset the origin so if someone taps on the left edge of a brick and then you reposition the object you'll reposition that point on the brick (and not reposition the bottom left corner of the brick).  To do that you'll need to convert the screen coordinates into coordinates in the actor's space.

That's all somewhat icky though.  I think you'd be better off just doing relative repositioning.  Instead of trying to position the brick absolutely with `setPosition` just reposition it relatively:

```
im.setPosition(im.getX() + dx, im.getY() + dy);
```

Then it doesn't matter where the "origin" is.

You'll have to compute dx and dy in your listener based on the previous touch point.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just for the record this is the final code: `code`im.addListener((new DragListener() {
       public void touchDragged (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer) {
        float dx = x-im.getWidth()*0.5f;
        float dy = y-im.getHeight()*0.5f;
              im.setPosition(im.getX() + dx, im.getY() + dy);
           }

       }));

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the drag listener gives coordinates relative to the origin of the actor that is raising the event. That is a bit strange when you are moving that actor in response to the drag events, because the origin keeps changing. Essentially, I found that if I just move the actor by the x and y values of the event, it will follow the mouse or finger.

One improvement is to record the position that the drag started at and use it as an offset, so the pointer stays the same distance from the actor's origin.

Another option might be to add the listener to the stage instead of the button. I expect the coordinates would then be relative to the stage's origin, which is not changing. I haven't tried that technique.

Here's [the code I used](https://github.com/donkirkby/vograbulary/blob/64988255705c57fae72a09aa3d78332293354853/vograbulary/src/com/github/donkirkby/vograbulary/russian/RussianDollsScreen.java#L83) to drag a button horizontally:

```
DragListener dragListener = new DragListener() {
    private float startDragX;

    @Override
    public void dragStart(
            InputEvent event, 
            float x, 
            float y,
            int pointer) {
        startDragX = x;
    }

    @Override
    public void drag(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer) {
        insertButton.translate(x - startDragX, 0);
    }
};
dragListener.setTapSquareSize(2);
insertButton.addListener(dragListener);
```

If you want to drag something in two dimensions, just copy the x code for the y position.